# MKOverlay color mismatch in XCode 6 and Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, mapkit

Setting MKOverlayPathRenderer.fillColor with UIColor is displaying wrong colours.

Examples:

for **RGB 0,255,0** should show green. Working as expected:

```
 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer!
{
    if overlay is MKCircle {
        var circle = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        circle.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 255, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        return circle
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Qlc.png

So Im trying to set specific colour now, close to cyan and its rendering white.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer!
{
    if overlay is MKCircle {
        var circle = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        circle.fillColor = UIColor(red: 43, green: 229, blue: 227, alpha: 1)
        return circle
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFbVx.png

Im I missing something there? How would I get the RGB value I want? Thanks for help

Comment: The RGB values should be from 0 to 1.  Try `(43.0/255.0)` instead of `43`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this extension to avoid typing `/255.0` over and over whenever you need to do this.

```
extension UIColor {

    convenience init(R r: Int, G g: Int, B b:Int, A a:CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat(r)/255.0, green: CGFloat(g)/255.0, blue: CGFloat(b)/255.0, alpha: a)
    }

    convenience init(R r: Int, G g: Int, B b:Int) {
        self.init(R: r, G: g, B: b, A: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Then you're good to go with:

```
circle.fillColor = UIColor(R: 0, G: 255, B: 0, A: 0.5)
```

and

```
circle.fillColor = UIColor(R: 43, G: 229, B: 227)
```